# Iconos no se ajustan con CSS

Tags: html, css

tengo este problema con HTML y CSS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven el primer icono se ajusta correctamente, pero los otros dos no y no entiendo la razón. Os dejo a continuación el HTML y CSS utilizado:

HTML

```
<div class="iconos-nosotros">
     <div class="icono">
                <img src="build/img/icono1.svg" alt="Icono seguridad" loading="lazy">
                <h3>Seguridad</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt officiis deleniti expedita adipisci quo neque, nihil soluta excepturi doloremque dolorum! Nobis minima rerum quis placeat voluptatem dolore earum cupiditate distinctio!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icono">
                <img src="build/img/icono2.svg" alt="Icono precio" loading="lazy">
                <h3>Precio</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt officiis deleniti expedita adipisci quo neque, nihil soluta excepturi doloremque dolorum! Nobis minima rerum quis placeat voluptatem dolore earum cupiditate distinctio!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icono">
                <img src="build/img/icono3.svg" alt="Icono tiempo" loading="lazy">
                <h3>Tiempo</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt officiis deleniti expedita adipisci quo neque, nihil soluta excepturi doloremque dolorum! Nobis minima rerum quis placeat voluptatem dolore earum cupiditate distinctio!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.icono {
    text-align: center;

    img {
        height: 10rem;
        width: 10rem;
    }

    h3 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
}

@include tablet {
    .iconos-nosotros {
        @include grid(3, 2rem);
    }
}
```

Cualquier ayuda en bienvenida. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Las dimensiones de alto y ancho de tu archivos distorsionados son iguales al que se presenta bien y que tengan la misma relación de diseño con el fondo de la imagen?

Comment: incluye las primeras líneas de los svg a ver si están con las dimensiones o el viewport raro

Answer (score 0):

Trabájalo con pixeles  a ver como te va.

```
.icono {
    text-align: center;

    img {
        height: 30px;
        width: 20px;
    }

    h3 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
}

@include tablet {
    .iconos-nosotros {
        @include grid(3, 2rem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado cambiarlo a px pero me gustaría conocer la raíz del problema, para poder seguir usando rem en todo el proyecto, alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: rem Tamaño de la letra del elemento raíz.